# Is it possible to edit items via SIF

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework, powershell

Installing `Sitecore Commerce 9.0.3` with adjusted URLs (changing everything localhost), I made adjustments to the installation process with SIF.

For example, I fix the localhost URLs in the `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config` to the correct value with a custom SIF module.

Now I am thinking about fixing the Url in the Link field of the item `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/Commerce/BusinessTools`

Is there any way to do this with SIF? I mean, if there is a way to do this with Powershell, it should be possible.

Comment: If you use SIF to install SPE and SPE Remoting, you should be able to run a post install PS script that would update the item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looking at the documentation I'd rather just change the field value by hand as the implementation looks a bit over the edge for this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it in Powershell, there is a good chance you can configure it within SIF. Read the docs on how the tasks are created.

You will probably need to use the Register feature to allow you to configure other PS cmdlets as Tasks or ConfigFunctions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can do following:

1. Create an aspx page in "SiteUtilityPages" that will read item from core database and update the url in field.
2. Add a Cmdlet in exiting SIF module or create one that will run the above page using "Invoke-RestMethod" command.
3. Add new task in your json file to call the cmdlet with appropriate parameters.

I have updated XC installation scripts for the similar purpose, [here is the blog](https://vipinbankablog.wordpress.com/2019/01/08/install-multiple-sitecore-commerce-instances-on-single-machine/) and you can download the updated installation scripts files from there.